# How to change the codec of BinStorage in Pig

Tags: hadoop, compression, apache-pig

I see there is not much compression took with default BinStorage function in Pig. I would like to use my own compression technique or snappy or others.

How can change the compression (codec what we call) of Pig function BinStorage?

Answer (score 0):

BinStorage does not support compression.

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#binstorage

Comment: Thanks for your research and answer. The output content of BinStorage is mostly a human readable. What is the use of using BinStorage?

Comment: BinStorage is mainly used by Pig to store intermediate data when running MR jobs. And it's not in a human-readable format but maintains in a machine-readable format.